# Premultiplication by an elimination matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

Let $$A = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 3 & 3 & 1
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Which, I want to convert to $I_{4\times4}$ by premultiplying by elimination matrices.

Now, the row operations are:

First column: $R_2 \leftarrow R_2 - R_1, R_3 \leftarrow R_3 - R_1, R_4 \leftarrow R_4 - R_1$

Second column: $R_2 \leftarrow R_3 - 2R_2, R_4 \leftarrow R_4 - 3R_2$

Third column: $R_4 \leftarrow R_4 - 3R_3$

Now, when I eliminate one column at a time, I get
$$ 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -3 & 1
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & -2 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & -3 & 0 & 1
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        -1 & 0 & 0 & 1
        \end{bmatrix} A = I_{4\times4}
$$
Where each matrix eliminates entries from each successive column. When I multiply those matrices together, I get 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & -2 & 1 & 0 \\
        -1 & 3 & -3 & 1
        \end{bmatrix}A = I
$$
and thus, this matrix is the inverse of $A$.

However, if I try to write eliminate all columns at the same time, using only one elimination matrix and the row transforms described above, I get 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        -1 & -2 & 1 & 0 \\
        -1 & -3 & -3 & 1
        \end{bmatrix}A \neq I
$$

Why is there such discrepancy? Why does eliminating one column at a time gives the correct answer whereas eliminating all columns simultaneously does not?

Comment: I don't understand. Why did you change the signs in the last matrix? The *only* matrix which will invert your $A$ is the one you got by multiplying the elementary elimination matrices.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel The last matrix represents all row transformations in a single matrix, doesn't it? For example element $-1$ in 2nd row and 1st column represents the operation $R2 \leftarrow R2 - R1$

Comment: No, $\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & -2 & 1 & 0 \\
        -1 & 3 & -3 & 1
        \end{bmatrix}$, the product of the elementary matrices, does.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Why does that matrix represent those transformations and why does the one which I described not, is exactly my question.

Comment: I see. Well, first of all, why do you think the last matrix should work? You can clearly see that if you multiply $L_1$ by $L_2$ from left, the entries in the first column of $L_1$ change.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel I've described my (obviously wrong) reasoning in the question description and comments above.

Comment: @taninamdar the matrix you produce corresponds to performing all operations simultaneously, that is, using only the rows that appear in the original matrix.  In the usual process of elimination, we successively perform operations on "new rows", from which the first however many columns have been deleted.  In doing so, we make sure we don't accidentally let a non-zero entry appear in an earlier column. Does that make sense? If not, let me know.